# How to reuse a variable obtained from a loop in a subsequent loop in ejs?

Tags: yaml, ejs, hexo

I'm currently working on a menu for an hexo.io site using data from a YAML file and EJS. My point is to generate a menu with sections and subsections directly from the data included in the YAML file.

The yaml file in _data/menu.yml

```
sections:
  Section1:
  Section2:

section1:  
  Activate:
    url: /activate
  First steps: 
    url: /first-steps
```

My ejs file

```
<% for (var section in site.data.menu.sections) { %> 

    <ul>
        <li>
            <%= section %>
            <% for (var i in site.data.menu.section) { %> 
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="<%= site.data.menu.section[i].url %>"><%= i %></a></li>
                </ul>    
            <% } %>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <hr>
<% } %>
```

My goal is to reuse the section variable in the second loop so that I can get a menu displaying :

- Section1

  - Activate
  - First steps
- Section2

Until now, I couldn't find how to properly insert this variable in the loop conditions. And I do not wish to hard code section names in the second loop.

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to do it unifying everything. it could still be optimised but works for me so I post it in case others have the same issue:

YAML

```
sections:
  section1:
    title: Section 1
    sub:
      Activate: /activate
      First steps: /first-steps
  section2:
    title: Section 2
```

EJS

```
<% for (var i in site.data.menu.sections) { %>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <%= site.data.menu.sections[i].title %>
            <% for (var j in site.data.menu.sections[i].sub) { %>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="<%= site.data.menu.sections[i].sub[j] %>"><%= j %></a></li>
            </ul>
            <% } %>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <hr>
<% } %>
```